# Xerces for Android

Tags: java, android, maven, xerces

I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.Error: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found
```

I have tried importing the jar files from maven but I'm getting this exception:

```
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\JOHN\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidDevelopment\MyApp\app\libs\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
```

Does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing the `jar` file directly, try adding the following dependency to your `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1:org.apache.xerces:2.9.0'
```